# How to use the "Using" statement in ASP.net razor webpages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

So I need to add a "using" statement which is :

```
using System.Data.SqlClient
```

in my webpage so i dont have to call whats inside the SqlClient with the whole statement

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new ..
```

How to do that ?

note that i added the reference System.Data to my webconfig file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

At the top of your Razor View just add

```
@using System.Data.SqlClient
```

Notice the `@` char before the using statement.

Or inside a block like below:

```
@{
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
}
```

---

**Side note:** it's a little bit weird to use a `SqlConnection` into a Razor View.

Comment: what do u mean with "Razor view" ? its a asp.net webpage (.cshtml) not MVC view, btw it worked thanks

Comment: It's not a good practice to use a SqlConnection into a Razor (cshtml). Great that it works. Can you mark it as answer then :)

Comment: where im supposed to use it ? and i will

Comment: First use it into your controller action before sending the data to the view. After that learn something about best practices in MVC hence ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Dude already told u im not using MVC -_- its ASP.net webpages its totally different thing

Comment: Nope :D It's ASP.Net MVC because you are using razor view which have an cshtml extension.  You only use cshtml with ASP.Net MVC and Razor ;-)